# How to disable images and stylesheets in playwright of Go?

Tags: go, chromium, playwright

I'm using Chromium and Playwright under Golang.

I'd like to disable images and stylesheet, so have tried below code:

```
browser, _ := pw.Chromium.Launch(playwright.BrowserTypeLaunchOptions{
        Headless:        playwright.Bool(false),
        ChromiumSandbox: playwright.Bool(false),
        ImageEnabled:    playwright.Bool(false),
})
```

However, this code is not working.

How to disable images and stylesheets in playwright of Go?

Thanks for your assistance!